# Make Chrome Resources available offline (for dev work)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, proxy, cache, offline-files

I like to do web development work while being on the train, with poor connectivity...

Most content I look at in my Chrome browser comes from the local server but a very few resources come from remote servers (a tiny image or two, and a few REST calls (XHR/Ajax).

So I wonder, if there is a Chrome extension/option to aggressively fall back to a cache of these XHR requests, if found offline? (ideally also in blatant denial of any expiry policies from request headers...)

May be it is possible, somewhere around [„enable offline cache mode“](https://addyosmani.com/blog/offline-mode-chrome/), but after all it's not about being fully offline, as `localhost://` should show. So, from a browser's perspective it's more of a **„mixed mode“, fall back to cache only for what's unresponsive...**

So you see, it's a bit more complicated than the average offline mode question...

**Perhaps there's a proxy solution (under Ubuntu) for this scenario?**

Or could I tweak header for those non-local websites to ("cache and do not ask (no Epub etc) for 48hrs")? (in Chrome with an extension, of course chrome itself must fall for that...)